# jFreechart CategoryDataset sort columns

Tags: jfreechart

I create a multi series linechart and fill its dataset dinamically:

```
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
for (Map.Entry<Long, TreeMap<Integer, Integer>> entrya : mtypes.entrySet()) {
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> atypes = entrya.getValue();
    if (atypes.isEmpty())
        continue;

    Long aid = entrya.getKey();
    String name = (aid < 2 ? "Важное" : (aid < 3 ? "Негатив" : "Позитив"));
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entrym : atypes.entrySet()) {
        int m = entrym.getKey();
        dataset.addValue(entrym.getValue(), name, Integer.valueOf(m + 1));
    }
    image = PDFUtil.printLineChart(writer, "", "", "Баллы", dataset , 500, 0, true);
```

Source array atypes for one series has the form:

```
{
1={2=4, 3=1}, 
2={0=1, 3=1, 4=1}, 
3={0=3, 1=16, 2=31, 3=2, 4=12}
}
```

All numerical keys in the map sorted Ascending, but on the chart the columns values are unsorted (horizontal axis):
[image: unsorted columns in CategoryDataset]

How can I sort it Ascending? This code didn't help:

```
chart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis().setColumnRenderingOrder(SortOrder.ASCENDING)
```

Comment: Why not use an `XYSeries`? "By default, items in the series will be sorted into ascending order by x-value…"

Comment: @trashgod Yes, XYSeries suits me. But generally, I'd like to display on X-axis months names: January, February etc, not the numbers of the months. Because LineChart didn't sort months in right order, I decided to use numbers instead of names. But it didn't fix sorting. If nothing works with LineChart, I will use XYLineChart. But I'd like to understand how to fill dataset correctly so that the sorting will be normal

Comment: Have a look at `ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart()`, and use [`setDateFormatOverride()`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20setDateFormatOverride) to get the desired format; for more specific help, [edit] your question to include a [mcve] the shows your current approach.